# Place images in google street view

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I am trying to confirm if one can place image in a google map street view and get a response when clicked

Searched a lot, also at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview
but couldn't find anything

if it's possible than can anyone post an instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a custom `Marker` with a custom image:

```
  var testMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 40.729681, lng: -73.991138},
      map: map,
      icon: 'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=dollar|FFFF00',
      title: 'Test'
  });

  testMarker.addListener('click', function() {
    console.log("test");
  });
```

Hope this helps!